# multiple select option html form data in mysql select query

Tags: mysql, sql

We have a html form field Protocol an values TCP, UDP,HTTP etc etc.. there are total of 16 values like this.

Now when a user select multiple protocol options on the form and submit. mysql query should fetch the matching HOST records with protocols available on that.

for example: A user select TCP and IPV6 as options and submits the form and user should get the records of associated hostnames for the protocols. it must match two protocols.

i am storing records in database like this way

```
Hostname        Location           Protocol
---------      ----------          ---------
host1            USA               TCP, UDP, IPV4, IPV6, HTTP
host2            AUS               TCP, IPV4, SMB, SMTP
host3            UK                TCP, NFS, SMTP, IPV6
```

For the above user query i need to return only host3 option which only matches the protocol options.
I tried LIKE option but if i have more option this looks ugly and also tried IN option that select any of the protocol and returning the results, i need to check all options.

how to get or query multiple options in mysql select query?

Comment: Hate to break it to you but, the problem is your database design.  It might be easy to store those lists, but it's exceptionally difficult to do anything useful with them.

Comment: there is no native way to do it but you can apply `FIND_IN_SET()` for each passed protocol's value and to construct a query like: `WHERE FIND_IN_SET('TCP', Protocol) AND FIND_IN_SET('UDP', Protocol)` and so on.